# Is it okay to create clicklisteners (or other listeners) inside a viewmodelscope?

Tags: google-maps, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I have a a fragment containing a googleMap where I am creating a bunch of Markers (which also is clickable). They are spiced with different information (colors, shapes and so on) from a room livedata query. In addition I have some MaterialButton buttons (which are styled as pushbuttons) where I toggle the Marker visible status on. At the moment, the "setup" of theese markers takes some time (200ms-2 secs, depends of amount of markers). To get out of that waiting, I was planning to use a viewmodelscope. Since there are some clicklisteners for theese buttons defined in there (they should do some action with the markers), will they still be alive when the viewmodelscope coroutine section ends, and If they are alive, do they still live in the correct coroutine-context, and do I need to do some housekeeping on the listeners when fragment and/or viewmodel ends?

I.E:

```
class MapsFragment:Fragment(){

   private lateinit var mapsViewModel : MapsViewModel
   private lateinit var googleMap : GoogleMap

//...
   override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        mapsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MapsViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentMapsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root:View = binding.root
//...
      return root
   }//onCreateView   

//...

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState:Bundle?){
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
//...

      mapFragment?.getMapAsync(_googleMap->
         _googleMap?.let{safeGoogleMap->
            googleMap = safeGoogleMap
         }?:let{
            Log.e(TAG,"googleMap is null!!")
            return@getMapAsync
         }   
//...
      
         mapsViewModel.apply{

            liveDataMapsListFromFiltered?.observe(
               viewLifecycleOwner
            ){mapDetailList->
                
               viewModelScope.launch{ 

                
                  binding.apply{

                     //...
                     siteMarkers.map{
                       siteMarker.remove() //removes existing markes from map on update
                     }
                     siteMarkers.clear() //empty the siteMarker array on update 
                     //...
                   
                     mapDetailList?.map{
                        it.apply{
                           //...
                           coordinateSiteLongitude?.let { lng->
                              coordinateSiteLatitude?.let { lat->
                                 siteMarkerLatLng = LatLng(lat,lng)
                                 siteLatLngBoundsBuilder?.include(siteMarkerLatLng)
                              }
                           }
                           //...
                           siteMarkerLatLng?.let { safeSiteMarkerLatLng ->
                              val siteMarkerOptions =
                               MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(safeSiteMarkerLatLng)
                                    .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                                    .visible(siteMarkerState)
                                    .flat(true)
                                  .title(setTicketNumber(ticketNumber?.toDouble()))
                                    .snippet(appointmentName)//TODO: Consider build siteId instead
                                    .icon(siteIcon[iconType])
                              siteMarkers.add(
                                  googleMap.addMarker(siteMarkerOptions) //Here are the markers added
                              )
                           }//siteMarkerLatLng?.let
                         

                        }//it.apply
                   
                     }//mapDetailList?.map

                     onSiteCheckedChangeListener?.let{
                        fragmentMapsMapTagSelector
                           ?.apTagSelectorMaterialButtonSite
                           ?.removeOnCheckedChangeListener(it) //clearing listener on button before update
                     }
                   
                     onSiteCheckedChangeListener = MaterialButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { siteButton, isChecked ->
                            
                        siteMarkers.map {
                            it.isVisible = isChecked
                        }
                     }.also {
                        fragmentMapsMapTagSelector
                          ?.mapTagSelectorMaterialButtonSite
                          ?.addOnCheckedChangeListener(it)
                     }

                     //Will this onCheckedChangeListener still survive when this viewmodelscope runs to the end ?
                   

                  }//binding.apply

               }//viewModelScope.launch

            }//liveDataMapsListFromFiltered.observe
         
         }//mapsviewModel.apply   


      }//getMapAsync
   
   }//onViewCreated

}//MapsFragment
```

Comment: What do you mean by "viewmodelscope comes to an end"? There's a property of ViewModel called `viewModelScope` that is a CoroutineScope used to run coroutines, which has nothing to do with the code you've shown. You've retrieved the ViewModel in the Activity's lifecycle, so the ViewModel's lifetime will match that of the Activity that is hosting this Fragment.

Comment: I actually forgot the viewmodelscope line... sorry for that, I will refrase my Q shortly.

Comment: Then I have added the `viewModelScope.launch`. By doing it this way, I hoped to avoid a lag at the moment when the Markers are set up and made ready. The hiding/unhiding works well bu using the visible parameter per marker (itarate through them when observing the checked change on the buttons). But I worry that by using this viewmodelscope, the "base" isn't there when the viewmodelscope ends, so the fragment doesn't kill my onchangelisteners on the buttons when the fragment dies.

Comment: ...or do I need some "clever" `withContext` clamping, like first `withContext(Dispatchers.Default){ ... }` inside the `viewModelScope.launch` and spice it with `withContext(Dispatcher.Main){...}` for each writing to a View descendant. BTW: Can you read a View (or descendant) with a Dispatchers.Main context (not affecting (changing) the UI ?).

Comment: ... and how do I preferably stop theese coroutines.  I have bound my viewmodel to the Activity not the Fragment. So I might have problem with the viewmodel outliving the fragment, and when the fragment dies the references to the views vil be invalid since the viewmodel still are alive (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what a CoroutineScope is. It determines the lifecycle of coroutines that it runs, but not of the objects created in the process of running those coroutines.

`viewModelScope` is a CoroutineScope that automatically cancels any coroutines it is running when the associated ViewModel is torn down. The coroutine doesn't know what you're doing with it. Cancelling a coroutine merely stops it from running to completion, like returning from a function early. In your code, you set your listeners and haven't stored references to them besides in the views they are set to, so their lives are tied to their respective view's lives.

If you were going to use a coroutine in your fragment to set up something for your UI, you would use the Fragment's `lifecycleScope`, not the ViewModel's `viewModelScope`. Like if you were fetching something to show in your UI, you would want that coroutine to be cancelled when the Fragment is destroyed, not the ViewModel which might be outliving the Fragment.

Your use of a coroutine in your example code looks pointless, because I don't see any blocking or asynchronous suspend functions being called. You mentioned setting up site markers is taking like 200ms. I'm not familiar with Google Maps since I haven't used it in the past several years, so I'm not sure which part is time-consuming. Usually, UI elements do not allow you to interact with them on background threads, so you might be out of luck. But maybe the time-consuming part is allowed to be done on background threads. You'll have to read the documentation. Using a coroutine for this won't make it take less time, but can prevent the UI from stuttering/freezing.

If you were going to do some long computation with a coroutine, you would need to switch dispatchers to do the blocking work and interact with the UI elements back on the main dispatcher. Simply putting something in a coroutine doesn't make it take less time, but it provides a convenient way to do something on another thread and then continue on the main thread after the result is ready. For example:

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted { // lifecycle coroutines launch on main thread by default
    val result = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { // switch to dispatcher for background work
        doTimeConsumingCalculation()
    }
    // back on main thread:
    applyResultsToMyViews(result) 
}
```

By using `launchWhenStarted` instead of `launch`, a Fragment's `lifecycleScope` will pause the coroutine when the Fragment is not attached, which will prevent potential crashes from trying to update UI using `requireContext()` or `requireActivity()` when there is no Activity.

Comment: Thanx for answering so good, this clears things. I wasn't aware of `launchWhenStarted`, this might help out of some tricky bits, but I wonder if the listeners also you define in the fragment "stops" when the fragment is not attached when using launchWhenStarted... so if you clicked a button (which reacts with a listener of course) and attempt to destroy the fragment at nearly the same time (I.E.: turning your device 180 degree), will this also stop the listener ?

Comment: The coroutine has nothing to do with the lifecycle of the objects that are created by the coroutine. It doesn’t make a difference whether they were created in a standard function or any kind of coroutine. When a Fragment is destroyed, its views and everything its properties reference will get garbage collected. This includes listeners. The Fragment is torn down on the main thread and your view listeners are also called on the main thread so you don’t have to worry about these things happening at the same time.

Comment: Ok, thanx very much !!

Comment: BTW (I may post this in a separate Q if it interesting to know). I actually tested your approach with `launchWhenStarted` and to test some effects here and there. I first made a wrapping with `withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {...} ` and inside there I tried to read the isChecked value from a `MaterialButton` like this `val state = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { myMaterialButton.isChecked }`. To my suprise this didn't crash! I thought you needed to do all kinds of actions (setting / reading) in the Main thread. Or is this only necessary when setting values / doing actions ?

Comment: I don't think reading properties from Views off the main thread ever causes a crash. Setting values from another thread *can* cause a crash but sometimes it succeeds. Some View methods are designed to immediately throw a RuntimeException if they detect they're being called off the main thread. Others will not and could therefore end up with inconsistent state and synchronization issues.